# How to limit TCP connections with nginx for HTTP/2?

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, http2

I want to use nginx as a https frontend and I'm looking for a way to limit  TCP connections. These limits should be based on the remote IP addresses and work for *HTTP/1.1* as well as *HTTP 2*.

For *HTTP/1.1* I thought I would be fine around 15 concurrent connections per IP (since most browsers seems to use at most 6), wich should be more than enough for *HTTP/2*. But the [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) states:

> In HTTP/2 and SPDY, each concurrent request is considered a separate connection.

And the [HTTP/2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.5.2) states about the `SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS` parameter:

> It is recommended that this value be no smaller than 100, so as to not unnecessarily limit parallelism.

Does this mean that I should allow at least 100 connections per remote IP? It seems so in my tests, but maybe I'm missing something. Because this seams to  essentially mean that I can't set any *meaningful* limits for the number of concurrent TCP connections, without seriously limiting *HTTP/2*.

Comment: IMHO, this depends on your architecture and your work load. What do you want to achieve? What problem(s) do you try to solve? I'm flagging this as "too broad" for now.

Comment: I want to enforce a limit of 15 concurrent connections per IP and a request rate of 1–3 req/s (with a burst value around 150). I'm unsure on how to write this because I'm unsure what qualifies as request and what as connections in HTTP/2 vs HTTP1. I'm not sold on the numbers, they will be tweaked later…

Comment: Seems a valid question to me - that nginx documentation is a bit confusing. It seems to say this will treat each stream as a connection, which would make it difficult to set a sensible limit for both HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 clients. Seems a bit silly to be honest. Should be easy enough to test it though. Set the limit to 1, try to connect from a browser (that supports HTTP/2) and see if that rate limits it to one connection stream.

Comment: You could set different limits for HTTP <2 and HTTP =2, depending on the protocol, leveraging the `map` module. Regarding your main question: Just test and see how it goes? I still don't understand how we could help with that, or better, you're able to help yourself, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, I do test this for myself and to no big surprise, the documentation seems right. I was hoping I'm missing something ;) This behavior seems very counterintuitive to me.

Comment: a) "[...] Because this seams to essentially mean that I can't set any meaningful limits for the number of concurrent TCP connections, without seriously limiting HTTP/2.": Well, as written above, you've to use different limits, depending on the protocol the user is using. b) Please ping me via @, otherwise I won't be notified.

Comment: @gf_ different limits for different HTTP versions seems the way to go. How can I set those? I know the _map_ module but I don't know how to get the HTTP version.

Comment: Use `$server_protocol`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved it for now:

```nginx
map $http2 $v1ip {
    default "";
    ""  $binary_remote_addr;
}
map $http2 $v2ip {
    default $binary_remote_addr;
    "" "";
}

limit_conn_zone $v1ip zone=v1ips:10m;
limit_conn v1ips 10;

limit_conn_zone $v2ip zone=v2ips:10m;
limit_conn v2ips 125;
```

Since the connection limit for HTTP/2 has to be that high, I also added rate limiting… but I'm still tweaking the values.

**NOTE**: while this allows setting a "sensible" value for HTTP < 2 connections, it still requires an — imo unnecessary — high number of concurrent connections for HTTP/2 connections. I would very much like to see `limit_conn` to only care for TCP connections and not HTTP requests.

Comment: Really neat. One of the gems in ServerFault.com. Thanks!

Comment: That allows 135 connections in total per IP address. Ditch `$v2ip`, and create two limits `key=$v1ip limit=10` and `key=$binary_remote_addr limit=125`.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is pretty good, if with whitelist I think using "" is not good.

should be use $request_id to replace "" be better

```
geo $whitelist {
      default 0;
      127.0.0.1/32 1;
}

map $http2 $http1_ip {
      default $request_id;
      "" $binary_remote_addr;

  }

map $http2 $http2_ip {
      default $binary_remote_addr;
      "" $request_id;

  }

map $whitelist $http1_ip_final {
      default $http1_ip;
      1 $request_id;

}

map $whitelist $http2_ip_final {
      default $http2_ip;
      1 $request_id;

}

    limit_conn_zone                 $http1_ip_final zone=conn_limit_per_ip_http1:10m;
    limit_conn                      conn_limit_per_ip_http1 10;
    limit_conn_zone                 $http2_ip_final zone=conn_limit_per_ip_http2:10m;
    limit_conn                      conn_limit_per_ip_http2 125;
```